# SVG being displayed differently on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: svg, cross-browser, difference

I have one svg but it looks differently on Chrome and Firefox: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OParwx.

```css
svg {
  fill: black;
  stroke: black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0,0,48.266,51.827">
  <g>
    <path d="M16.69 41.827c-2.763 0-4.975 2.237-4.975 5s2.212 5 4.975 5c2.763 0 5-2.237 5-5s-2.237-5-5-5"/>
    <path d="M40.19 41.827c-2.763 0-4.975 2.237-4.975 5s2.212 5 4.975 5c2.763 0 5-2.237 5-5s-2.237-5-5-5"/>
    <path d="M26.768 20v-20 20z" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M36.768 10h-20 20z" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path d="M0 5.059h6.406l10.99 22.455h20.469l10.401-18.777" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M45 37.689h-29.947s-3.594.077-2.579-4.036l4.923-6.139" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" fill="none"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Here's how they look like

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

What makes them different and how to fix it?

Edit: a temporary solution (besides waiting for the bug is fixed on Firefox 37) is to remove stroke-miterlimit and add stroke-linejoin="bevel"

Comment: Looks good (like first picture) for me in FX 24 and 35.

Comment: my Firefox is 36.0.1, not sure if there's changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suffering from [bug 854296](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=854296) It's a Windows only bug that will be fixed in Firefox 37 so not long to go now.