# Adjacent lines inside svg path with stroke-width

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg with multiple lines inside a path.

```
<path stroke-width="13" stroke="black" fill="orange" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 Z L200 300 z"/>
```

Because of the stroke-width the lines intersect[image]

Is there any way of making the path continuous without altering the "d" attribute?

Edit:

I am interested in how you can control the joins of multiple objects inside the same path while having a stroke-width defined.

If I would change the "d" attribute and remove the middle Z so that the lines form a triangle the stroke problem would disappear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you control how an SVG's stroke-width is drawn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241393/can-you-control-how-an-svgs-stroke-width-is-drawn)

Comment: I don't believe it's a duplicate. I'm more interested in how to handle the join between objects while having a stroke-width rather than changing the stroke's location.

Comment: You're suffering from [bug 854296](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=854296) It's a Windows only bug that will be fixed in Firefox 37 so not long to go now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one hell of an overhang for two lines that meet at a point. (Are you using Firefox by any chance? [I saw something very similar recently.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29096688/1679849))

If you want a neat join between two disjoint line segments, your best bet would be to draw them with rounded end caps by adding `stroke-linejoin="round"` and `stroke-linecap="round"` to the path element.

And if my suspicion is correct, you can fix the overhang problem by changing `fill="orange"` to `fill="none"`. Try this:

```html
<svg viewBox="50 50 400 400" width="350" height="350">
  <path stroke-width="13"
        stroke="black"
        fill="none"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        d="M 100 100 L 300 100 Z L200 300 z"
        />
</svg>
```